# Problem with GRUB in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Arrows can't select Windows option

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, lts

A few weeks ago I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and Windows 10 in my Asus Zenbook 14 UX425EA-HM165T. Both of the installed OSs worked well for me.

Today, without downloading and updating anything, I am unable to select the *Windows* option from the GRUB menu. I have both the *Ubuntu* (this works fine) and the *Windows* options, but I can't use my keyboard arrow keys to change a selection.

[image: GRUB menu]

I tried to use `boot-repair`, but this did not solve the problem.

Any of you can help me?

Comment: Can you possibly add pictures or something about what you mean? I am having trouble understanding what you mean by "arrows can't click in Windows option".

Comment: I will try to share some pictures. I mean, that when you go down with the arrows, you can't go in the windows option. It is as if the option was not there.

Comment: Do you mean that when you select the option and hit Enter, the option spits an error or causes a restart? I have had that happen before, and that is the only visualisation I have of what you are describing. Please tell me if I am wrong!

Comment: Is difficult to explain and never I have seen this problem.
Now, in the question, you have the images. I have the option and I can’t select the windows option. All the others options yes, but in the case of windows option, no. When you move the arrows to select the option, it jumps and goes to the option below. Is very strange…

Comment: Maybe LB Did It, you have the knowledge how to solve this problem?

Comment: The best way I solved this was to install rEFInd boot manager instead of GRUB. This only works if you can actually boot into a drive however. If you cannot boot into anything, then your best bet is to manually boot a drive via the grub-efi emergency command line in your boot manager. I will link the thread if you need me to.